# Youtube API returns zero results if setting orderby

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

Using Youtube API v2 to retrieve uploads in specific channel.
When setting the parameter "orderby" to "published" the API returns zero results.
This worked previously, stopped working today (2014-08-28).

E.g.
works:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/PewDiePie/uploads?orderby=published

doesn't work:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/PewDiePie/uploads

I'm aware the v2 protocol is deprecated, but it's been promised to be around up until April 2015.
Can anyone shed light into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was shortage in service of the API:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6603

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to an issue I just filed with Google/YouTube: [YouTube Gdata API suddenly stopped working.](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3613&thanks=3613&ts=1409243662)  Go to this link and star the issue, and maybe they will fix it.